# Calculating Intercepting Vector

Tags: c#, math, vector

I have 2 objects (i'll refer to them as **target** and **interceptor**).
I know the target's current location and velocity.
I know the interceptor's current location and speed it can travel.

From that, what I now need to know is :

- Is interception possible ie same location at same point in time.
- What vector would the interceptor need to travel on
- How much time will the interception take

i.e target @ (120,40) with a V(5,2) per second and interceptor @ (80,80) that can travels with a speed of 10 per second.

I've looked around and found plenty of ways to find out what point they meet and they all revolve around the angle between the two vectors and as I don't know the second vector and I can't calculate that and I'm getting lost trying to resolving this.

Any suggestions or guidance on how to proceed?

Comment: I believe you also want to know the interceptor velocity vector, else you can do no calculations...

Comment: Velocity is speed with direction, i already know the speed, so once i have the vector that expresses the direction i will have the Velocity,

Comment: Once you have the intercept point you can calculate the distance the vectors travels.  So time it take to reach the intercept point is t = s/v.  Assume the start time is the same for both vectors.  Then t1 and t2 should be equal.

Comment: @jdweng: everything i've found requires the vector to calculate the interception point,  I know that Interceptor location + Velocity * time = target location + velocity * time where time is the same for each. but i'm getting lost trying to rearrange the equation to find interceptor velocity when i don't know the time

Comment: I think it's possible to find the interceptor's heading if you only know its speed, the target's velocity, and both of their starting positions. I'm working on getting my idea into in a comprehensible form now.

Comment: Consult http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circles_of_Apollonius#Apollonius_pursuit_problem

Comment: First get distance point travels use sqrt((x1 - x2) ^2 + (y1 - y2) ^2).  Time is just s = vt.  You know s & v.  They gave you  v(x) = 5 and v(y) = 2 [v(5,2)] so again v is sqrt(v(x) ^2 + v(y) ^2) = 5.38

Comment: @Kevin thanks, i'm certain its possible, and nearly certain that the answer requires generating a simultaneous equation from the basic trig. because i can calculated the vector from the current locations, which when combined with the   target velocity will let you calculate the tangent of the angle which will give you the magnitude of the vector and that would give you the angle of the interceptor vector... but keep getting lost trying to formulated it

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark, i've not heard of Circles of Apollonius before it looks like it could be the solution but that stub aticle doesn't give much detail

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can compute the intersection with a 2D vector calculation. The target moves along a line. We know the starting point of the target, its direction and speed.

At any time t >= 0 the target is at point x defined by

[image]

where s_t is the starting point of the target (120, 40) and v_t is the velocity vector of the target (5, 2).

We know the interceptor's starting point (s_i), its speed (v_i), but not its direction. We can describe the interceptors range by a circle around the starting point, whose radius increases over the time. In vector calculus we get

[image]

where x is a point on the circle, s_i is the starting point of the interceptor (80, 80), r is the radius (or range) of the interceptor at time t, and v_i is the speed of the interceptor (10).

When the target and the interceptor meet at time t, their location x must be equal. We use the x of the line equation in the x of the circle equation and get

[image]

That's just a normal [quadratic equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation) for t:

[image]

You can easily solve this. In this case you get a valid and an invalid solution:

t1 = -5.2328 => invalid because t must be >= 0

t2 = 8.61307

Now that you know t, you can compute the intersection point with the first line equation. Target and interceptor meet at (163.065, 57.223)

Comment: I like this answer.  You could also note that there are cases when the interceptor can't catch the target - this will occur when your quadratic doesn't have real roots == when the linear term in the quadratic squared (commonly b^2) is less than 4 * the square term * the constant term (4*a*c).  I know this isn't the case for the example in Q, but in general it could happen

Comment: Quickly implementing my own answer, I also get (163, 57) at time 8.6 So we're either both right or both wrong :-D

Comment: Just want to double check what the arrow above the variables signifies

Comment: @MikeT: Variables with arrows above are [vectors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_vector), variables without arrows are real numbers.

Comment: @gdir Thanks that about what i thought but wasn't 100% it wasn't to indicate a normalized vector, did have me rather confused until i realised that you were using the dot notation for multiply not the dot Product

Comment: "You can easily solve this." --> Sorry but I don't understand how to solve this. Aren't `a`, `b` and `c` vectors in this quadratic equation? How can you get a single number out of solving the equation instead of another vector?

Comment: Ok, thanks to another answer [here](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/14582/68213) I realized I was actually supposed to use the dot product and it worked fine. The last comment of MikeT had me a bit confused and the fact that you used the `.` for multiply in the very first equation threw me off a bit but I got it working, thanks.

Answer (score 7):

Given:

At time 0, the target is at point A and the interceptor is at point B. At some point in the future, they will intersect at point C.

line segment *a* is opposite point A, and likewise for *b* and B, and *c* and C.

[image]

---

We know the positions of A and B. We can derive the angle CAB from the target's heading. We know that the ratio of the lengths of line segments *a* and *b* equals (interceptor.speed/target.speed).

First, find angle CAB.
Let vector B^ be equal to the target's velocity.
Let vector C^ be equal to (interceptor.position.x - target.position.x, interceptor.position.y - target.position.y).
Determine the angle between them using the dot product formula.

```
B dot C = ||B|| * ||C|| * cos(angle)
cos(angle) = (B dot C) / (||B|| * ||C||)
angle = arccos((B dot C) / (||B|| * ||C||))
```

...Where "dot" is the [dot product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product), and ||B|| is the scalar magnitude of vector B. `angle` is angle CAB.

Now we'll find angle ABC.
Using the [law of sines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_sines), we know that `sin(ABC) / b == sin(CAB) / a`. 
Rearrange the equation into `ABC = arcsin( sin(CAB) * (b/a) )`.
We found CAB in the last step, and we know that b/a is target.speed/interceptor.speed, so plug those values in and find ABC.

Now that you know two angles and two points, you should be able to derive the position of C. Angle ACB is equal to 180 - (CAB + ABC) if you're using degrees, or Pi - (CAB + ABC) if you're using radians. Use the sine law to determine the lengths of sides b and c. Now you can find T using `T = b / target.speed`, and C using `C = target.position + (target.velocity * T)`.

---

My C# is a little rusty, so [here](http://ideone.com/x1jVMn) is a sample Python implementation instead. Let's plug in your sample values, and the result is:

```
Collision pos: Point(163.065368246, 57.2261472985)
Time: 8.61307364926
Angle A: 113.198590514
Angle B: 29.6680851288
Angle C: 37.1333243575
a: 86.1307364926
b: 46.3828210973
c: 56.5685424949
```

The position and time are the same as the ones found by gdir, so I'm pretty confident that both our approaches work.

Edit: MikeT: the C# version

```
public static double Dot(Vector a, Vector b)
{
    return a.X * b.X + a.Y * b.Y;
}
public static double Magnitude(Vector vec)
{
    return Math.Sqrt(vec.X * vec.X + vec.Y * vec.Y);
}
public static double AngleBetween(Vector b, Vector c)
{
    return Math.Acos(Dot(b, c) / (Magnitude(b) * Magnitude(c)));
}

public static  Vector? Find_collision_point(Point target_pos, Vector target_vel, Point interceptor_pos, double interceptor_speed)
{
    var k = Magnitude(target_vel) / interceptor_speed;
    var distance_to_target = Magnitude(interceptor_pos - target_pos);

    var b_hat = target_vel;
    var c_hat = interceptor_pos - target_pos;

    var CAB = AngleBetween(b_hat, c_hat);
    var ABC = Math.Asin(Math.Sin(CAB) * k);
    var ACB = (Math.PI) - (CAB + ABC);

    var j = distance_to_target / Math.Sin(ACB);
    var a = j * Math.Sin(CAB);
    var b = j * Math.Sin(ABC);


    var time_to_collision = b / Magnitude(target_vel);
    var collision_pos = target_pos + (target_vel * time_to_collision);

    return interceptor_pos - collision_pos;
}
```

Comment: Thamls Kevin Just trying to get my head round the algebra now

Comment: I'm not 100% sure how to tell whether the interception is possible at all. I suspect either 1) arccos will fail because the argument is out of range; 2) arcsin will fail for the same reason; or 3) All possible positions of C will have a negative collision time.

Comment: @Kevin It'll be the arcsin that will fail and the "some reason" will be that the quantity `sin(CAB) * b / a` is greater than 1 (or less than -1).  The arccos *can* fail, but only due to rounding error (for nearly colinear B^ and C^).

Comment: @Kevin, i think i'm going to have to give the answer to gdir, i think your both right but his solution is much easier to read for anyone else trying to do this. thank you for your help though

Comment: This is wrong. Its not using linear algebra vectors at all; this answer is using a trig approach which is waaaaaaaaaay slower.

Comment: Well, define "wrong". If the OP didn't forbid the use of trigonometry, and if the result is correct, what's the problem?  I'll cop to "this isn't the best approach" :-) but that's a far cry from "wrong".